# How to remove a specific field that matches condition in foreach processor?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my mappings definition.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "properties": {
                    "cell_type": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "content": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "question": {
                "properties": {
                    "cell_type": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "format": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "content": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "answer": {
                "properties": {
                    "cell_type": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "format": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "content": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that question and answer fields are array for for most of the cases. But I want to avoid indexing a content field when a format field has multiline.

So I define the following pipeline to remove a content field.

```
{
    "description": "remove content field",
    "processors": [
        {
            "foreach": {
                "field": "question",
                "processor": {
                    "remove": {
                        "field": "_ingest._value.content",
                        "if": "ctx.format == 'multiline'"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "foreach": {
                "field": "answer",
                "processor": {
                    "remove": {
                        "field": "_ingest._value.content",
                        "field": "ctx.content"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The document still has content fields even if a format field is set to "multiline". The condition doesn't seem to work as I expected.

Is it possible to access a content field wit any variables in the foreach processor or to remove content fields in question or answer array?

I'm using elasticsearch 7.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a much simpler approach using a `script` processor instead:

```
{
    "description": "remove content field",
    "processors": [
        {
          "script": {
            "source": """
            ctx.question.stream()
              .filter(x -> x.format == 'multiline')
              .forEach(x -> x.remove('content'));
            ctx.answer.stream()
              .filter(x -> x.format == 'multiline')
              .forEach(x -> x.remove('content'));
            """
          }
        }
    ]
}
```